# Crear y guardar imagen php

Tags: php

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya quiero guardar una imagen que me llega por la varaible `$_FILES`, y quiero guardala en una carpeta que yo le indique, pero el problema es que buscando en internet no he podido encontrar un lugar para hacer eso, tengo en mente hacerlo algo como lo hace laravel, indicando el archivo a subir, el directorio y el nombre para ser guardado pero no he encontrado informacion de como hacerlo, ya que no se como crear imagenes con php, he encontrado paginas como [esta](https://altruistas.org/crear-una-imagen-con-php/) donde crea la imagen desde 0 pero  no he podido encontrar una forma de hacerlo como les explique. Desde ya gracias :)

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent pero no puedo agregar codigo ya que no he intentado con ninguno, ya que no conozco una forma de hacer eso, ni con palabras como `fopen`o `mkdir` ya que no me dejan poner al archivo a subir tratándose de una imagen

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent o tu dime que agrego? o que le hace falta a mi pregunta

Comment: ¿Revisaste la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.php)?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent esta bien no hay problema, solo que no se que mas informacion darle al post, hasta el link que me paso Sal me esta ayudando, no les pido el codigo les pregunto si saben como puedo hacer eso no el codigo si no mas bien una funcion o algo asi

Comment: no has investigado nada??? de lo que investigaste escribes código... si ese código tiene algún fallo; entonces lo traes y se te ayuda con el código ... no escribimos código fuente para usuarios que no han demostrado que hayan intentado hacer la tarea por si solos...

Comment: y todo eso esta en la documentacion que te pase que no has leído ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent lo se, he leido de manera detallada mas veces de las que puedo contar con los dedos de las manos el como preguntar o el que no preguntar, etc, pero si en este caso desconozco la forma de hacerlo, ¿que código pongo? o que agrego, lo que intente lo agregue

Comment: tienes que investigar he intentarlo ... decir no se y no tengo codigo, no es argumento para una pregunta ... vaz a recibir votos negativos ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent por eso vine a SO, porque pase al rededor de una hora buscando y no encontre lo que buscaba

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131332/discussion-between-arcanis-the-omnipotent-and-david-flores-garcia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si entiendo bien pero lo que estás preguntando creo que es con que función PHP se sube una imagen a tu servidor en la carpeta que quieras, si es eso es muy sencillo, así sería el ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'carpeta/' . $file);
}
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo es olo que buscaba

Comment: @Pablo trata de no responder preguntas que sean de este estilo. Como tu mencionas, `"es muy sencillo"`, el sitio no es para hacer la investigación de otros, es para ayudar con algún problema con el código. En especial cuando si buscas "subir imagen con php" en google, te aparece otra respuesta de este mismo sitio con la misma solución. (entonces la pregunta que el OP hizo es una duplicada, por que solución ya tiene)